# AWS lambda for file uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture

this is not a programming question as such, but I think this is the right place to ask this question.

My application is a spring boot application deployed in an AWS ec2 and the server is a t3.micro with just 1gb ram. The application itself is pretty stable and works smoothly. 
But when I try to upload files through the same server the server heap space gets exhausted and application gets killed. All the files are stored in s3. **Sometimes I might need to upload files upto 1Gb**

I have been thinking of using AWS lambda completely for my file upload and download needs, is this a good approach ? If anyone has faced a similar problem and have solved it using some other method, please let me know. Open for any suggestions.

Or if there is something I need to follow for file uploads that wont take up the heap space as much, that would also be helpful. At certain times there might be around 3k RPM to the same server.

The flow i was thinking was **client -> API Gateway -> Lambda -> S3**

Comment: If I understand what you mean ... no, using Lambda to proxy S3 uploads is not a good approach. Your webapp should vend time-limited, pre-signed URLs to your client. Your client can then upload files directly to S3.

Comment: I was trying to use AWS API Gateway to create a post API and hit the endpoint directly from the client which then triggers a lambda function and returns the path

Comment: Yes, you can have your client invoke Lambda via API Gateway and have the Lambda return an S3 pre-signed PUT URL, if that's what you mean by "return the path".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. 
I failed miserably trying to use the approach I thought of, because API Gateway maximum payload size is 10 MB

I ended up using [Jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) 's solution of using Pre signed urls to upload and download from S3. This approach will save the Application server's CPU considerably.
Thanks @jarmod and @prashant